# Crontab to create a new file

Tags: unix, cron

I'm trying to create a simple crontab that creates a file called log.txt every minute by populating it with a simple command's output. Right now this is what I've put into my crontab:

```
* * * * * (/usr/bin/ls <pathToRandomDirectory) > log.txt
```

By my understanding, the 5 asterisks correspond to "every minute". But when I run this the log.txt file is not being created. Is there something I'm missing here?

ALSO, if I didn't want to have an email sent to me whenever the job is created I found that I need to put the line:

```
>/dev/null 2>&1
```

Somewhere in my crontab file. Where exactly does this go? At the end of the command or on a separate line?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to put an absolute path for log.txt. Otherwise, it will be created in /.

Also, `>/dev/null 2>&1` has to be at the end of the sentence. If you want the 2 (meaning the errors) to be dismissed, just write `2>/dev/null`.

Then, your final cronjob would be like this:

```
* * * * * /usr/bin/ls pathToRandomDirectory > /pathToRandomDirectory/log.txt 2>/dev/null
```

Answer (score 1):

What exactly should be in that file? This creates a new file with the text "something" in it every minute:

```
* * * * * echo "something" > /path/to/your/file.txt
```

I had some problems with crontab especially when I created a new crontab config - my problem was that I had to insert an empty line at the end of the crontab - some systems need it to work correctly. So if you do

```
$ crontab -l
```

the output should be a list of your cron jobs on each line and then an empty line at the end.

Try it if it works for you. Sorry, but I'm not sure about the email, but I dont think that you need to put lines like that to crontab, play around with the configuration - it shouldn't send you any emails by default.